# How do I find the value of a variable in a specific string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, prepend

This is kinda confusing but i will do my best...

So i am writing a program that when someone clicks on the text, it subtracts the amount from the total. For example my html would look like this....

```
<form>
<input type='number' name='namea' id='ida' step='0.01'>
</form>
<div id='diva></div>
```

and then the javascript/jquery looks like this...

```
$('input[name=namea]').change(function(){
    var itemvalue = this.value;
    $('#diva').prepend('<p class = "pa">Blah blah ' + itemvalue + 'blah blah.</p>');
});
var total = 100;
```

and then this is the part i am confused on..

```
$('.pa').click(function() {
    //I want to find itemvalue of the one that i click on and subtract it from total.
})
```

so i can find the current value of itemvalue... but how do i find it of a string that was prepend a few strings ago.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you isolate that text in a span or something?

Comment: Ya but then all of the prepends would be in the same spam right? @sje397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are clicking on the dynamically added element, you can store the `itemvalue` as data to the element

Ex

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input[name=namea]').change(function(){
        var itemvalue = this.value;
        var pa = $('<p />', {
            class: 'pa',
            html: 'Blah blah ' + itemvalue + 'blah blah.'
        }).data('itemvalue', itemvalue).data('otherdata', 'othervalue')
        $('#diva').prepend(pa);
    });

    $('#diva').on('click', '.pa', function() {
        alert($(this).data('itemvalue'))
        alert($(this).data('otherdata'))
    })
})
```

It will give the values of `itemvalue` n time back

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WjeMT/)

Comment: but then i could still only find the current value of itemvalue right?

Comment: Thanks so much.. but how do i set n to automatically be the number i clicked on

Comment: @user2433384 see the update, is that what you are looking for

Comment: @user2433384 you can add as many data as you want, need to use different keys that's all

Answer (score 0):

try this

html+script :

```
<head>
    <script>
    function substract(){
        var a = document.forms.yourform.input.value;
        var total = document.forms.yourform.total.value;
        var b = total-a;
        document.yourform.hasil.value= b;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="yourform">
        <input name="total" type="text" oninput="substract(this.value)" >
        - <input name="input" type="text" oninput="substract(this.value)">=
        <input name="hasil" readonly="readonly" >
    </form>
</body>
```

may it helps you :D